# Isn't 'make' program built-in the gcc-arm-none-eabi library?

Tags: windows, makefile, cross-compiling, arm-none-eabi-gcc

My English is poor because I'm not a native English speaker.
I hope you to understand.

I downloaded gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2020-q2-update-win32.exe version on the https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads

I made sure the command related to arm-none-eabi works well as below.
[image]

But oddly enough 'make' command doesn't work as below.
[image]

Isn't 'make' program built-in the gcc library (or gcc-arm-none-eabi)?
Or did I use 'make' command wrong?

I would be grateful if someone can tell me how to solve this problem

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU Make is not built into GNU GCC. They are different products.

Installation instructions can be found at the official site: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/